# XCode 6.3.1 crashes while update provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

Today I updated my Xcode to version 6.3.1. When I open my ios project and updating the provisioning profiles the Xcode crashes. 
If any one can help me I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: I'm Hitting the same issue. Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 2):

1. Close XCode
2. Delete all files under `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`
3. Open XCode and refresh your account provisioning profiles

Answer (score 0):

Clear out everything in Xcode to find the issue.

[This should help](http://miraclechow.blogspot.com/2014/02/deleting-xcode-cache-cleaning-build.html)

Comment: I clear out everything , and reinstall Xcode , when I updating provisioning profile crashes again.